# Does postmates support tracking_url in iframe

Tags: iframe, postmates

My code for postmates tracking_url :

```
<iframe src="https://postmates.com/track/del_LtCu2--LzNXzjk" width="100%" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen ></iframe>
```

But it will give an error like this:

> Refused to display 'http‍s://postmates.com/track/del_LtCu2--LzNXzjk' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.

I am using nginx on ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Did you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666423/overcoming-display-forbidden-by-x-frame-options ?

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the error message is qutie specific.

Try seeting the `X-Frame-Options` to

```
ALLOW-FROM https://yourhost.com/
```

Here is some explanation: [X-Frame-Options](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options)

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible. You will need to create your own map that uses the courier's current location lat/lng. You can get these values via the webhook.